# Is the sentence "Paul drinks much milk" grammatically correct or not?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, quantifiers, polarity-items

I'm doing my homework. The question is

> Is this sentence
> ‘Paul drinks much milk.’
> grammatically correct?

For me the answer is yes, because the quantifier "much" is used before non-count noun. But according my book my answer is wrong. Anybody can help me, please?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think [the lesson on Learn English Today](http://www.learn-english-today.com/lessons/lesson_contents/grammar/a_lot_much_many.html) is very clear.

> **A lot of** can be used in  all sentences: affirmative, negative and interrogative.
>   **Much and many** are used in negative and interrogative sentences.
>   They are rarely used in affirmative sentences, except if they begin the sentence.

So, the sentence in the question is most commonly written or spoken as: *"Paul drinks a lot of milk."*

The context seems informal, and using "much" in an affirmative gives a more formal tone that sounds odd when used for a simple statement like that one.

Here is an example of using "much" in an affirmative sentence from an [article on theguardian.com](http://www.theguardian.com/business/economics-blog/2014/dec/07/aid-bill-uk-commitment-development-gordon-brown): *"There was much talk last week of how he would be remembered for keeping Britain out of the euro[...]"*

It is common to use "much" in a negative, as in: *"Paul doesn't drink much milk."*

or in a question, like: *"How much milk does Paul drink?"*

"Much" is also used with too or so, as Damkerng T. points out: *"Paul drinks too much milk."* or *"Paul drinks so much milk!"*

Comment: Another way to make it okay is using *so much* or *too much* instead of just *much*.

Comment: I love reading questions on this stack exchange. As a native English speaker, I don't notice some of the weird little rules, that even some really simple words have! I'm glad I didn't have to learn it as a second language!

Comment: I'd really hate to believe that "rarely used in" and "grammatically correct" are mutually exclusive.  But maybe that's a WHOLE other topic.

Comment: @DavidWallace I don't follow. It's not grammatically incorrect to say for example "There was much debate." but it is formal sounding and it would probably be better for a learner to use "a lot of" in most affirmatives until they have more mastery.

Comment: Oh, I don't query that at all.  "A lot of" wins hands down, and I wouldn't advise a beginner to say anything else. I guess I'm just being overly pedantic about the fact that the question was "Is ... grammatically correct"; which an answer of "... are rarely used" doesn't quite address.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ah, I see. I answered the question to explain why the book said the sentence wasn't correct, not to answer the question that was in the book. I don't much care for the question "Is this grammatically correct?" because there are a lot of ways to be grammatically correct and still make it impossible for folks to understand you :) I should probably explain more about formal/informal though. I'll give it some thought.

Comment: Right, I see.  The answer to "why does the book say this is grammatically incorrect" is an entirely different matter.  I hate to label this kind of sentence as "incorrect".  It's unusual, sure, and I wouldn't use it myself.  To say it's outrightly wrong seems to take things a bit far.  But certainly, if I were teaching an English course for beginners, or writing a grammar book for beginners, I would tell them to avoid sentences such as "Paul drinks much milk".

Comment: In addition to all the above, I feel the need to point out that the playful/ironic use of "much" in positive sentences (well, fragments), is [one of the characteristics of "doge speak"](http://the-toast.net/2014/02/06/linguist-explains-grammar-doge-wow/).  Which means ELLs are at real risk of encountering it in the wild, as it were, as a form of language play currently a fad among native speakers.

Comment: I swear: English speakers don't do it just to be impossible on purpose.

Comment: @Codeswitcher I look forward to the meta discussion on whether doge is on topic like headlinese or legalese ;)

Comment: @Colleen I agree with this for 'much', but I think 'many' can be used regularly in affirmative sentences with no issue : "Paul ate many cakes", "The speaker answered many questions" - but perhaps you meant this to only apply to uncountable nouns?

Comment: @kandyman what I included in my answer is specific to this question about milk. You should read the article I linked for a more general discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is that much isn't about countability, but about emphasizing the increased size when compared to another. Sentences with "much" in them are almost always have an implicit comparison that isn't stated. In your example "Paul drank much milk today" doesn't have an unstated comparison.

Answer (score -2):

The sentence is: " Paul drinks much milk "

Here,    Paul - subject
(Drink + s ) - verb
Much - adverb
Milk - object

Actually, much and many are used only in negative sentences and questions. But also, much is used for uncountable nouns. So, here MILK is uncountable. Then we can use it.

As well MUCH is used for emphasizing that people, things, situations,....etc are very similar.

Example:

> If I'm going to a club, I wear much the same as I wear for work.