# When can we use 'much' in affirmative clauses?

Tags: determiners, modifiers, grammar-myths

I found the below in [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/much-a-lot-lots-a-good-deal-adverbs) web-site:

> We use much in questions and negative clauses to talk about degrees of something.
>
> **We don’t use much in affirmative clauses**.

Also, it the same web-site, I found the following:

> She runs **much** faster than he does. [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/much)

also I noticed that some web-sites use *much* with *affirmative clauses*:

> May we all be having this **much** fun and getting this **much** exercise when we're his age! [PJ Media](https://pjmedia.com/video/meet-the-79-year-old-man-who-still-rollerblades-everywhere/)

Is it Okey to use *much* in *affirmative clauses*? If yes, when can we use it? and what is the rules?

**Update:**

Here is another example on how often the word "much" is used  in informal style:

> After **much** consideration I will NOT be performing at the Inauguration with my improv group Capitol Hill-arious [Ike Barinholtz](https://twitter.com/ikebarinholtz/status/821207865058672640)

Comment: There is much more to the word "much" than this question reveals :)

Comment: When determinative "much" is used as a **determiner**, it is mostly restricted to non-affirmative contexts ("We don't have much money"). But in examples like "She runs much faster than he does", "much is not a determiner but a degree **modifier**. That's the difference.

Comment: @BillJ That is terrible wording then. Dictionaries should be careful when they say stuff like that, learners aren't supposed to doubt what they read in them.

Comment: This question about [Paul drinks much milk.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/41398/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends how you use **much**. Looking at the first sentence you quoted, it is clear that **much** qualifies the comparative adverb **faster**.

> She runs **much** faster than he does.

If you use the simple adverb rather than the comparative, it doesn't work:

> She runs much fast -*wrong*
>   She runs a lot fast -*wrong*
>   She runs very fast *OK*

If you remove the last half of the sentence so that **much** qualifies the whole sentence, it doesn't work, but it's OK if you use **a lot** instead or if you change it to a negative statement:

> She runs **much** - *wrong*
>   She runs **a lot** - *OK*
>   She doesn't run **much** - *OK*

Looking at the other sentences you quoted:

> May we all be having this much **fun** and getting this much **exercise** when we're his age!
>
> After much **consideration** I will NOT be performing at the Inauguration with my improv group

In these examples, **much** qualifies a non-count noun, not a sentence. That is covered by [this page](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers).

Note that, when qualifying a noun, **a lot of** is more likely to be used than **much**. unless it follows some other qualifier like **this**, **how**, **too** or **very**, where one cannot use **a lot of**.

Let's look at the situation when **much** qualifies an adjective:

> He is much good - *wrong*
>   He is **a lot** good - *wrong*
>   He is much **better** - *OK, because better is a comparative adjective*
>   He is **very** good - *OK*
>   He is **not** much good - *OK*
>   He has done much **good** - *OK, because good is a non-count noun in this context*

---

To sum up:

If **much** qualifies a simple adverb, a simple adjective or the whole sentence, you can use it in a negative sentence but you can't use it in an affirmative sentence- you must use **a lot** for sentences and **very** for simple adverbs and simple adjectives.

If it qualifies a comparative adverb or a comparative adjective, you can use it in negative and affirmative sentences.

If it qualifies a non-count noun, you can use it in negative and affirmative sentences, though usage in affirmative sentences is rare unless it is preceded by a further qualifier.

Comment: Don't you think it often sounds awkward if you use 'much' with nouns in affirmative sentences? Would you really say something like: "There is much water on the floor."?

Comment: Old fashioned, maybe, but not wrong. Next to a formal word like consideration, it seems appropriate, and **much water** is used in the stock phrase "much water has flowed under the bridge"  https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=CEkyo7Wb7hgC&pg=PA15&dq=%22much+water+has%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22much%20water%20has%22&f=false

Comment: No matter how many times I repeat it, "We need much sugar for this cake." still does not sound alright. There are restrictions as to when you can use 'much' to modify a noun in affirmative sentences. Try using it to qualify something other than a subject and/or an abstract noun.

Comment: +1 to JavaLatte.  @fluffy: *This cake recipe uses much sugar* is a perfectly normal sentence, and *Does this cake recipe use much sugar?* is a perfectly normal question. *We have much work to do.*

Answer (score 2):

> Much [as a determiner] sounds **very formal** in *positive statements*. It is usually better to say *a lot of*:
>
> *There was a lot of food left.*
>
> ✗ Don’t say: There was much food left.

Source: [Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/much)

The examples you provided, except for the one before *faster* which is an adverb, sounds formal to me although it seems they were intended to be humorously said in a formal style (..much consideration..., May we..). In addition, *this much* is considered to be spoken, it's not just *much* alone it's more like combinations of *so much*, *too much*, and *how much*.

Comment: While "a lot" is informal, "much" is hardly "very formal".

Comment: @TRomano Please post your comment on [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/much) website, they could use a suggestion then. I'm just directly quoting.

Comment: Understood that you were quoting.