# A lot of or Much?

Tags: sentence-structure

Hello is it correctly to ask "do you drink much tea?" it sounds weird for me, but i haven't found any explanation saying it's incorrect. As I know "much" and "a lot of" interchangeably used with uncountable nouns, don't they?

I always ask 'do you drink a lot of tea?"

Comment: Related question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/41395/9161

Answer (score 1):

### Generally, you can use either

Both are fine as a question. As a statement, "much" is used to express excess:

> Do you drink much tea?
>
> He drinks *too* much tea.
>
> **But NOT**: He drinks much tea.

and

> Do you drink a lot of tea?
>
> He drinks a lot of tea.