# Should “much” be omitted in “as much sarcastic as I am”?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, comparative-constructions

Is it grammatically correct to write a sentence like this:

> I enjoy spending my time with people who are as much sarcastic as I am.

Or the “much” should be omitted?

Comment: Definitely discard ***much***. And many people would reduce ***as I am*** to just ***me***.

Comment: I'd like to hope someone more clear-sighted than me might be able to explain exactly when you do and don't need the word ***much*** after comparative ***as***. It might be to do with adjectives vs nouns *(I'm **as** good as you* vs *I have **as much** money as you),* but I'm not sure that's the whole story.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a sentence where "are" and "much" would work. "...have as much" free time/money would work.

Comment: @Jontia *people who are as much of a beach lover as I am* - the switch between plural and singular makes this very awkward. It would be more usually said *people who are beach lovers like me* or *people who love the beach as much as I do* The singular like: *she is as much of a beach lover as I am* would be ok though.

Comment: The main issue here is that much + an adjective does not work comparatively. Not that much and are cannot be used in a sentence.....As much as I like you, you are as stubborn as a goat.

Comment: @Lambie I think the “are” points to a word that won’t work with “much”. *You are as much sarcastic as me.* vs. *You have as much sarcasm as I do.* The “are” isn’t the problem exactly, but it points to where the problem might be.

Comment: @ColleenV The are does not point to anything; You are as sarcastic as me. The issue is not the are. it is, however, "much sarcastic". Anyway, I have addressed this as much as I feel is necessary in my answer.

Comment: I noticed you didn’t use “much” after “are”... that was the only point I was trying to make.

Comment: @Lambie I have finally come up with a valid sentence using “are much”... *Adjustable lighting and climate controls are much needed improvements.* Compound adjective for the win ;)

Comment: Related question (but not a duplicate): [Is the sentence “Paul drinks much milk” grammatically correct or not?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/41395/9161)

Comment: @ColleenV I do not understand what you are doing or where you are going in all your comments. The **main point** in the question is that "much sarcastic" cannot go with a adjective in a simple comparative. Simple comparatives are: as [adjective] as. In "as much needed as" much is an adverb, not an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

Comparative adjectives:

- to be as rich as I am
- to be as sarcastic as he is

The comparative is formed by: as....adjective .....as
Much is not needed.

- He doesn't **need** this explanation as **much** as you do. Comparative use of *much*.

Notice the **quirky thing** here:

- He likes music **a lot**. Or: a great deal. *Declarative.*
- He likes music much. [BUZZER, NOT IDIOMATIC, A MISTAKE]
- He doesn't like music much. Or: He doesn't much like music. *Negative.*
- Or: He doesn't like music a lot. (also the negative forms)
- He doesn't like music **as much as** you do.

**as much as** is a comparative adverb above.
**as rich as** is a comparative adjective.

BUT: **as much as** can also be a comparative adjective:

- He has **a lot of talent**. Adjective.
- He has as much as talent as she does. Comparative adjective.
- He has as little talent as she does. Comparative adjective.

Comment: Or "He doesn't like much music" - Only a few pieces of music are enjoyed.

Comment: @Jontia Well, think about this: much is for quantities. He doesn't like much (a lot of) coffee (at a time). He only likes a little coffee (at a time). So, generally, if he only likes a few pieces of music, we are more apt to say: He doesn't like most music. He only likes some jazz. Also, "He doesn't like much music" would mean: He doesn't like some "quantity" of it being played at some time. L:ike during work hours, for example. "He doesn't like much music at dinner". But that is so very awkward.