# Can I use "much" like this?

Tags: usage

> **Much** political debate is meaningless.

Is it possible to use "much" like this? I could not find this usage described in any dictionary, but I remember reading similar usages many times. Am I using it correctly or should I say instead "Much of" or any other expression?

Comment: Related question (not a duplicate): [Is the sentence "Paul drinks much milk" grammatically correct or not?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/41395/9161)

Answer (score 5):

It's a perfectly acceptable usage. The definition of *much* is *a great quantity of*, so you don't need to add another *of* unless you are limiting your statement to a particular category of something, for example "Much of the political debate I see on TV is meaningless".

Comment: Thank you Kate Bunting. According to Borgh's answer, "much of" must always be used to keep the text readable. This seems to be inconsistent with your answer. Who's right?

Comment: "Much ado about nothing" comes to mind.

Comment: Well, naturally I think I am! Others seem to agree, to judge from the voting.

Comment: @KateBunting - Imho there aren't enough votes to reach that conclusion. Let's see if more people answer or vote. Contradictory answers are so frustrating!

Answer (score 3):

**Much** is used with **uncountable nouns**; its meaning is akin to *a lot (of)*, and *lots (of)* Many grammar books for learners and English websites advise that *much* should only be used in questions and in negative sentences, but that's an oversimplification, it can also be used in affirmative sentences.

- **How much** fear and distrust is there in the world? (interrogative)
- There is *a lot of* fear and distrust in the world.
  There is **much** fear and distrust in the world. (formal)
- There isn't *a lot* we can do  (pronoun)
  There isn't **much** we can do   (pronoun)
- There isn't *a lot of* time left.
  There isn't **much** time left.
- A *lot of* fun was had by all.
  **Much** fun was had by all. (formal)
- *A lot of* money was spent on buying drinks.
  **Much** money was spent on drinks.  (formal)

The authoritative  *[Advanced Grammar in Use](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Advanced_Grammar_in_Use_with_Answers/NY8oAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=In+affirmative+sentences+we+generally+use+a+lot+of+rather&pg=PA100&printsec=frontcover)* by Martin Hewings says:

[image: screenshot of Unit 50, Advanced Grammar in Use]

> In affirmative sentences we generally use **a lot of** and **lots (of)** rather than **much (of)** and **many (of)**, particularly in informal contexts. However, there are a number of exceptions–
> In formal contexts, such as academic writing, **much (of)** and **many (of)** are often preferred. […]
>
> - **Much** debate has been heard about Thornton's new book
> - **Much of** her fiction describes women in unhappy marriages
>
> In formal contexts we can use **much** and **many** as pronouns:
>
> - There is no guarantee she will recover. **Much** depends on how well she responds to treatment.

From *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/much)* we also have the following examples

> 1. They set about the task with **much enthusiasm**. (also *a lot of enthusiasm*)
> 2. Add ***this much water*** and no more (*this much* is indicating a specific quantity, without changing the meaning it is not replaceable by “a lot of”.)
> 3. Take ***as much time as*** you like. (also: *as long as*)
> 4. I have **much hope** for the future. (In this instance, *much* is modifying the uncountable noun *hope*)
> 5. I have **much need** for a new assistant.
> 6. He left her, **much to** the satisfaction of her other suitor. (In this instance, *much to* is not replaceable by *a lot of*)
> 7. From those to whom **much has been given**, **much is expected**. (Luke 12:48)

The Biblical quote was the inspiration for John F Kennedy's famous line

> For of those to whom **much is given, much is required**. And when at some future date the high court of history sits in judgment on each one of us–recording whether in our brief span of service we fulfilled our responsibilities to the state–our success or failure, in whatever office we may hold, will be measured by the answers to four questions…

All the affirmative sentences with *much* are grammatical, and they will sound formal to native speakers. But in everyday speech and informal writing, the expressions *a lot (of)*–and even more informal–*lots (of)*, will usually be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers) states that

> We use ***much*** with singular uncountable nouns:
>
> - I haven’t got ***much*** *change*.
> - There is ***much** concern* about drug addiction in the US.

Here, ***debate*** is used as an [uncountable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/debate) noun, to mean *debating*.

***Much of*** comes in handy, but in these situations:

> When we use ***much*** or ***many*** before ***articles*** (a/an, the), ***demonstratives*** (this, that), ***possessives*** (my, your) or ***pronouns*** (him, them), we need to use ***of***:
> Claude, the seventeenth-century French painter, spent ***much of** his life* in Italy.

That's why even the set phrase ***[not much of a](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/not-much-of-a)*** includes the article ***a***:

> - not much of ***a*** problem
> - not much of ***a*** career.

So yes, you can use *much* in this way.

Here are some examples:

> - The study of myth continues to cause ***much debate*** among classicists.
>   (*The Times Literary Supplement*, 2012)
> - This week there has been ***much debate*** about metal detectors in schools.
>   (*Times, Sunday Times,* 2014) ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/much-debate))

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much%20debate%2C%20much%20of%20debate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that ***much debate*** is more common than ***much of debate***:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Are there rules against it? No.

Is it a common usage? also no. It is a stylistic choice you can make. If you are a songwriter who's trying to fit your lyrics into a certain meter people will understand what you are singing.

But that "of" in "much of" does a lot of work in keeping the text readable. Unless you have a specific reason to omit it I'd always go for "much of"

Comment: I have run "Ngram" with several examples and the versions without "of" seem much more frequent...?

Comment: Interesting! did you test the whole string?

Comment: I took out the predicate and tested various versions of "Much x"  vs. "Much of x". It would be great if someone could elaborate on the difference between both expressions.

Comment: You suggest that "much of" must be used to keep the text readable. However, according to Kate Bunting's answer, "much of" is only to be used when the statement refers to a particular category of sth. Who's right?

Comment: Language is a thing of consensus, you can never be right or wrong. However, people seem to disagree with me so I am apparently the minority here. So if you follow the majority opinion, go with Kate's answer.